# How to resolve 'Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent' error when trying to download files via web api call?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, download, asp.net-apicontroller

When I use a web api call to download a file, I can easily download the file. The only problem is I get **Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent** in my error logs.
Sorry if this is potentially a duplicate question, but none of the answers here have helped me.

```
<a href="/api/DownloadDocumentById?documentId=<%=doc.Id %>" download>
                                    <i class="fa fa-download text-primary"></i>
                                </a>
```

```
<HttpGet>
    <ActionName("DownloadDocumentById")>
    Public Function DownloadDocumentById(documentId As Integer)
        Dim document = xxxxxxxx

        Dim context = HttpContext.Current

        context.Response.ContentType = document.Type

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(document.Content, 0, document.Size)

        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", Baselib.FormatContentDispositionHeader($"{document.Name}"))

        context.Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())

        context.Response.Flush()

        context.Response.End()

        Return HttpStatusCode.OK // Have also tried to create a sub without returning a value
    End Function
```

As mentioned before, I can easily download the document, but still IIS logs **Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent** error. 
Again sorry of this is a duplicate question. Hope Someone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, I think you should add all headers before you start writing the actual output/content. With a buffered stream (which is what I'm about to suggest) this should not make a difference and is mostly only semantical, but since headers should be added *before* writing the content (content is always last) it may avoid similar issues in the future if you decide to use an unbuffered stream.

Therefore, I suggest you re-order your code accordingly:

```
context.Response.ContentType = document.Type

context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", Baselib.FormatContentDispositionHeader($"{document.Name}"))
context.Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(document.Content, 0, document.Size)
```

Now if you use an unbuffered stream the content will be sent to the client immediately when you call `OutputStream.Write()`, therefore in order to set the HTTP result afterwards you need to make sure that your entire response is buffered so that it isn't sent until your internal request (action and controller) has finished executing. This can be done by setting [`Response.BufferOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput?view=netframework-4.7.2) to `True` before outputting anything:

```
context.Response.BufferOutput = True

context.Response.ContentType = document.Type

'The rest of the code...
```

Finally, you need to remove the calls to `Response.Flush()` and `Response.End()` as they empty the buffer prematurely and writes everything to the client before you even get to return the status code.

New code:

```
(...)

context.Response.BufferOutput = True

context.Response.ContentType = document.Type

context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", Baselib.FormatContentDispositionHeader($"{document.Name}"))
context.Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())

Return HttpStatusCode.OK
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Works like a charm. I re-arranged the code as you said and NO MORE IIS error. Thank you sir. @Visual Vincent

Comment: @arvind : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a million!! @Visual Vincent

Comment: @VisualVincent, Response.BufferOutput is "true" by default. why setting it to 'true" fixes the issue?

Comment: @FLICKER I don't remember whether or not that was the case when I wrote the answer, but I think the solution to the OP's issue had more to do with the reordering of the function calls and the removal of the `Flush()` and `End()` calls. Explicitly setting `BufferOutput` was more of a good practice to ensure it was actually set (some settings can be controlled by `web.config`, for example).